# NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryUtils.getDefaultRetryPolicy

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

Previously I was creating directories in `hdfs` from java on a `single node cluster` and it was running smoothely but as soon as I made my cluster multinode, I am getting this error
The stacktrace I am getting looks like this

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryUtils.getDefaultRetryPolicy(Lorg/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration;Ljava/lang/String;ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/apache/hadoop/io/retry/RetryPolicy;
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.NameNodeProxies.createNNProxyWithClientProtocol(NameNodeProxies.java:410)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.NameNodeProxies.createNonHAProxy(NameNodeProxies.java:316)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.NameNodeProxies.createProxy(NameNodeProxies.java:178)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:665)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:148)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2811)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:100)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2848)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2830)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:389)
    at CreateDirectory.main(CreateDirectory.java:44)
```

here is the CreateDirectory class

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        String hdfsUri = "hdfs://localhost:9000/";
       //String dirName = args[0];
        String dirName=null;
      // String filename = args[1];
        String filename;

        if(args.length<=0) dirName = "ekbana"; filename = "text.csv";

        URL url = null;
        BufferedReader in = null;
        FileSystem hdfs = null;
        FSDataOutputStream outStream = null;
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        List<Map<String, String>> flatJson;
        Configuration con = new Configuration();
        try {
            url = new URL("http://crm.bigmart.com.np:81/export/export-sales-data.php?sdate=2016-12-01&edate=2016-12-02&key=jdhcvuicx8ruqe9djskjf90ueddishr0uy8v9hbjncvuw0er8idsnv");
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        }

        try {
            con.set("fs.hdfs.impl", org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.class.getName());
            con.set("fs.file.impl", org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem.class.getName());
            hdfs = FileSystem.get(URI.create(hdfsUri), con); // this is line 44 
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            System.out.println(hdfs.mkdirs(new Path(hdfsUri + "/" + dirName)));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The solution on many sites says that I need hadoop-common and I already have it and still I am getting this error.I doubt that the retry policy related to my setup, if not then why is this error ?

Comment: normaly a `NoSuchMethodError` points to incompatible jar files

Comment: @Jens thanks for your input . I am using hadoop-2.8 and hadoop-commons is also 2.8

Comment: in this Version there is no package retry as you can see [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/package-frame.html)

Comment: @Jens I just now tried with latest `hadoop.io` package (version 2.5), still I am getting same error

Comment: You can try to get an answer here: http://hadoop.apache.org/issue_tracking.html

Comment: In the sourcecode you can find this comment: `/**
   * Return the default retry policy used in RPC.
   * 
   * If dfs.client.retry.policy.enabled == false, use TRY_ONCE_THEN_FAIL.
   *`

Comment: Maybe it will help you to Switch of the retry mechanism

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148478/discussion-between-saurab-and-jens).

Answer (score 5):

Adding maven dependency helped:

````
```
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
       <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
       <version>2.8.1</version>
    </dependency>

```
````

Answer (score 0):

I highly endorse Yulia's answer which led me to understand and solve the problem I was having. You can do what she suggested OR add:

```
/path/to/hadoop-client/client/hadoop-hdfs-client-<version_number>.jar
```

to your **classpath** so that the **hadoop-hdfs-client** jar gets included at runtime.